# Error occurred while processing document for application/json in WSO2

Tags: java, json, curl, wso2

I have started learning WSO2 today, while going through this quick start guide

[Quick Start Guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI630/Quick+Start+Guide#4c9de6b778a140f49902453ae972cfef)
I have a problem when sending a request to the Enterprise Integrator using this curl command

```
curl -v -X POST --data r.json http://localhost:8280/healthcare/categories/surgery/reserve --header "Content-Type:application/json"
```

here's the exception details:

> TID[-1234] [EI] [2018-09-20 11:33:38,759] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamBuilder} - Error
>   occurred while processing document for application/json
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamBuilder.processDocument(JsonStreamBuilder.java:69)
>   org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:153)
>   org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:163)
>   org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:116)
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:145)
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:94)
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70)
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
>   org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:351)
>   org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:399)
>   org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcess(RESTRequestHandler.java:123)
>   org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:101)
>   org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:69)
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:303)
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:92)
>   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>   org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:337)
>   org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:383)
>   org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:151)
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is r.json in the curl command, try replacing r.json with @request.json

Answer (score 0):

In the CURL command, replace r.json with @r.json

The name of of the file should start with @

Comment: Can you test the same in either SOAP UI or POSTMAN to check if it is working or not